# How to count records with one distinct field in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nosql, mongoose

While exploring mongoose for nodejs I ran into the problem of needing to know the amount of user in my collection:

My collection has records, each record has a user. I want to know the amount of unique (different) users.

How can I do this with mongoose?

**EDIT:**

The database is growing quite fast, is there anyway to get the number back from the DB instead of getting all the distinct records and counting them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's an alternative answer as I get an exception when I try Reddest's approach with Mongoose 3.1.2 (which seems like a bug in Mongoose to me as Reddest's approach should be fine).

You can call the `distinct` method on your collection's model, specifying the name of the user-identifying field of that collection:

```
Record.distinct('user_id').exec(function (err, user_ids) {
    console.log('The number of unique users is: %d', user_ids.length);
});
```

Or if you want to chain the `distinct` call from a find, include the callback in the `distinct` call (this did work for me):

```
Record.find().distinct('user_id', function (err, user_ids) { ... });
```

**UPDATE**

If you just want the count without getting the values, stick a `count()` call in the chain:

```
Record.distinct('user_id').count().exec(function (err, count) {
    console.log('The number of unique users is: %d', count);
});
```

**NOTE**: this doesn't work in the latest Mongoose code (3.5.2).

Comment: see my update, is there a way without pulling in all the records?

Comment: @askmike Sure, I just added a version that does that.

Comment: Actually, I confirmed that chaining count as mentioned in the UPDATE does **not** applying the distinct filter. If you check the query output, you are getting the count of all records (or whatever filter you apply).

Comment: @bromanko Yep, I see what you mean.  It doesn't work in the latest code.

Answer (score 14):

Aggregation will work for you. Something like that:

```
Transaction.aggregate(
    { $match: { seller: user, status: 'completed'  } }, 
    { $group: { _id: '$customer', count: {$sum: 1} } }
).exec()
```

Comment: Why is .distinct('phone').count() not working in latest mongoose code?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want get the number of queried collections, you can use this:

```
Record.find()
      .distinct('user_id')
      .count(function (err, count) {
          //The number of unique users is 'count'
      });
```

Comment: Not sure about this solution, doing so, I always get 1 as count result

Answer (score 1):

You can do a distinct query.

```
var Record = db.model('Record', yourSchema);
Record.find().distinct('user').exec(callback);
```

Mongoose Queries:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

MongoDB distinct query:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation#Aggregation-Distinct

Comment: see my update, is there a way without pulling in all the records?

Answer (score 1):

I just needed the number of distinct musicians, but some of **the code above did not work for me**. If I used count and distinct together I just got the total number.

**This was my solution**:

```
/**
 * Get number of distinct musicians
 */

myList.find()
    .distinct('musicianName')
    .exec(function (err, count) {
        console.log(count.length);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for an answer & got this question, now I got the answer so replying to this question.

You can segregate all the users with similar property with below code. I have used email as an example you can change it. You will also get count of all the users with same value of the property you pick.

```
var agg = [{$group: {_id: "$email",total: {$sum: 1}}}];
User.aggregate(agg, function(err, logs){
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
  return console.log(logs);
});
```