# Row count per each distinct value of the field in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have a schema like `{ reactionType: String, userName: String }` (really simplified), and I want to count how many reactions of each type a given user has got. How do I do this with Mongodb and Mongoose?

I tried doing

```js
MyModel.find({ userName: 'myUser' }).distinct('reactionType').count()
```

and the variations of this, but this seems to count the reaction types present for a given user, not the count of *each* reaction type for the user.

In case this helps to clarify what I want, in SQL I'd do something like

```sql
SELECT ReactionType, COUNT(1) FROM TheTable
WHERE UserName = 'myUser'
GROUP BY ReactionType
```

but how to translate this to Mongoose-speak?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451575/how-to-count-records-with-one-distinct-field-in-mongoose) question that seems related, but it's solving a different problem and it didn't help given the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Aggregation Framework's [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operator:

```
MyModel.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { userName: 'myUser' }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$reactionType",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```